# App doesn't route audio to headphones (initially)

Tags: ios, swift, sinch, callkit

I have a VOIP app implemented using the Sinch SDK and CallKit. Everything works fine, apart from when the device has headphones plugged in. In the latter case, when the call starts, audio is still routed through the main speaker of the device. If I unplug and plug the headphones back in - during the call -, audio is then correctly routed to the headphones.

All I am doing is

```
func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
    guard let c = self.currentCall else {
        action.fail()
        return
    }

    c.answer()

    self.communicationClient.audioController().configureAudioSessionForCallKitCall()
    action.fulfill()
}
```

Shouldn't this be taken care automatically by the OS?

Comment: By "main speaker" do you mean the loudspeaker or the receiver (i.e. the speaker on top of the phone screen)? Moreover, can you show how do you configure the audio session?

Comment: I mean the loudspeaker. I don't configure the audio session myself. I am calling the method "configureAudioSessionForCallKitCall" from the Sinch SDK :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the Sinch SDK overrides the output audio port. Try to run this code just after the audio session has been configured:

```
do {
    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
} catch {
    print("OverrideOutputAudioPort failed: \(error)")
}
```

If it doesn't work, try to configure the audio session by yourself, instead of relying on Sinch SDK if you can. Replace the `configureAudioSessionForCallKitCall` call with something like this:

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
do {
    try session.setCategory(
        .playAndRecord,
        mode: .voiceChat,
        options: [.allowBluetooth, .allowBluetoothA2DP])
    try session.setActive(true)
} catch {
    print("Unable to activate audio session: \(error)")
}
```

Comment: For some strange reason, it works if I comment out the call to "configureAudioSessionForCallKitCall" and do nothing. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes, as I said: they probably override the output port (`overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)`). So if you need to call `configureAudioSessionForCallKitCall` for some reason, just call `overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)` soon after that. Otherwise, I suggest you to configure the audio session by your self—as you can see in the second part of the answer—to make sure that it's correctly configured. So that the audio session behavior is more predictable.